# Prepopulate from link in content only visible to users tagged within that content

Tags: 7, entities

I have two content types, Parent and Child. Parent contains a list of tagged users which may create Child. Child contains the tag of the Parent.

On the Parent page I need a link, which is only visible to people tagged in it, to create a new Child with the Parent already tagged in it.

I know I need to use something like **Entity Reference Prepopulate** but my problem is that I can't figure out how to make the link.

This seems like it should be a simple thing to do but I can't for the life of me figure out how!

The requirement is that this should only use the UI and **without editing any .php files** as there is no guarantee that other devs will be able to code and allows easy visual recognition of what has changed.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are 100 ways fo doing this, but I can't think of one without editing a php file at least once. You can tell your devs to install a module you have and they don't need to edit any php, but not without you making a module. Sorry

Comment: Would this be possible using [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php)?

Comment: Where do you want to display create child page link ? In Node Page Or in views results ? 

How are you tagging users to the parent node ? using entity reference field ?

Comment: @AnilSagar Either in node page or views would be fine. And yes, users are tagged by entity reference field.

Comment: I don't understand why your developers can't install a module you built. If you make a module and DO edit a few php files, they just need to install it, not recode it. And no views_php is not enough, because you could write enough php for the link to appear, but not for the form to be populated with the parent.

Comment: "you could write enough php for the link to appear, but not for the form to be populated with the parent" I'm probably wrong but doesn't Entity Reference Prepopulate step in at that point?

Comment: I would also ask what the ultimate goal is. It seems like you're trying to use a content type to control permissions for another content type. I would argue there's probably a better way to handle access control. With a better understanding of what you're trying to do (not how you're trying to do it) we might be able to help you find a better solution.

Comment: @Chaulky I'm using [Node Access User Reference](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) to control who can make Child content. I just need a button on each Parent which opens the page for making a new Child with an Entity Reference of Parents filled out with the Parent that the Child was made from.

Comment: If anybody could help with the hiding from unwanted users bit that would be great as I've figured out the rest (see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how to do it.

1. Install and activate [Entity Reference Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_prepopulate) and enable it within the Entity Reference of Parents field in Child. You can now populate that field by  **example.com/node/add/child?field_parents=[parent nid]**.
2. Install and activate [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php).
3. Create a new View without any pages or blocks called "Create new Child"
4. Click "+Add" and select "Content Pane"
5. Apply the following settings:

   - Filter critera

     - Content: Published (Yes)
     - Content: Type (= Parent)
   - Pane settings

     - Link to view: Yes
     - Argument input: From context>Node Content ID
   - Contextual filters (under advanced)

     - Content: Nid
6. Set Format - Show: Fields and then add a field - Global: PHP
7. In the configuration for Global: PHP, in the Output code section write:
   `<?php print '<a href="http://example.com/node/add/child?field_parent=' . (string)$data->nid . '">Create new child</a>'; ?>`. (N.B. You need title field/NID field added as well for the `%data->nid` to work, hide it if you wish)
8. Add a Global: PHP in "Filter Criteria" and add the following code

   `$uid = $GLOBALS["user"]->uid;`
   `$node = node_load($data->nid);`
   `$info = field_get_items('node',$node,'field_users');`
   `$uids = array();`
   `foreach($info as $user)`
   `{`
   `$uids[] = $user['target_id'];`
   `}`
   `return in_array($uid, $uids) ? FALSE : TRUE;`
9. Save everything. In in Pages now, you can add this into Panels via "View Panes".